# Gaussian Distribution little help in C

Tags: c, math, gaussian

I am trying to generate the Gaussian Distribution using Method 2 and Method 3 described here:
http://c-faq.com/lib/gaussian.html

The problem is I am little confused as I have sigma and Mean and the 100 numbers with the range of 0 to 1 but in these methods it just returns the value for the interval of 0 to 1 and in these methods the sigma and mean value has not been used.

Can anyone help me how can I generate a Gaussian distribution using these methods?

Comment: Isn't it just copy and paste?

Comment: If you have a distribution with mean=0 and stddev=1, then just multiply by the desired stddev, and then add the desired mean.

Comment: @oli that won't keep it normalized, would it?

Comment: @rubenvb: Define "normalized".

Comment: @oli integral is one, or N, as is proper for a probability distribution.

Comment: But this is about random numbers, so please ignore what I said. The question itself (without reading the link) is incredibly unclear on that.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yeah, I think the OP is after a random variable with a particular distribution, not the PDF itself.

Comment: My mean is approx zero but Standard deviation is 0.5. 
Let say according to the C code in the given link If I have 100 Numbers so I have to use the 'U' as 1st number and 'V' as the 2nd Number . Is this correct ? or I am going wrong

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code and describe what specifically isn't working. Your question, as worded, is too vague for us to help.

Comment: I have tried to make the code using the method defined at wikipedia 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution but with that I am not getting the correct answers , Now I cameacross this code . I have not start coding becuase I am confused at some parameters like sigma and mean . My sigma is 0.5 and mean is approx zero so I am thinking of modifying it according to my need , and this method gives a single value of the random number and I have 100 numbers so how to generate number for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the routines you linked to give random numbers (selected from a gaussian (normal) distribution) with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.  that's the usual way routines like these work.

it's quite easy to change that to any other mean and sd - you just multiple by the sd and *then* add the mean.

so, for example, if `x` was generated by one of the routines above, then

```
y = 0.5 * x + 0.1
```

will have a standard deviation of 0.5 and a mean of 0.1.

so you don't need a separate routine for each combination of mean and sd.  you just use the routines as given and then do the extra conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer,
I have 1 more confusion . 
Let say I have the array of numbers in which I have different floating points numbers between 0-1 and I want to generate the guassian distribution for that . SO I made this program kindly check where I am going wrong

`for (int k=0; k<o-1; k++)
{
 
 for (int k=1; k<o; k++)
 {
 if(phase == 0) {
  
  U = (rand() + 1.) / (RAND_MAX + 2.);
  V = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.);
  Z = sqrt(-2 * log(U)) * sin(2 * pi * V);
 } else
  Z = sqrt(-2 * log(U)) * cos(2 * pi * V);

 phase = 1 - phase;
 printf("\n%f",z);

}`

Comment: if you have code that doesn't work ask a different question.  but given that you haven;t marked this or any other response correct, ever, i certainly won't be answering...

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you I just need little help, that where I am going wrong , my previous comment is incomplete and program is wrong 

`a[3]={0.3,0.7,0.2,0.1};

for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
{

 
 for (int k1=1; k<4; k++)
 {

 if(phase == 0) {

  
  U = (rand() + a[k]) / (RAND_MAX + a[k1]);
  V = rand() / (RAND_MAX + a[k]);
  Z = sqrt(-2 * log(U)) * sin(2 * pi * V);
 } else
  Z = sqrt(-2 * log(U)) * cos(2 * pi * V);

 phase = 1 - phase;
 printf("\n%f",z);

}`
correct?

Comment: IF YOU HAVE CODE THAT DOESN"T WORK ASK ANOTHER QUESTION.

Comment: Sorry Sir I don't have the code , I just want to modify it according to my need , and I am not forcing you to give me the answer , If you don't know then it's ok :)
Thanks for the help sir :)

Comment: So sorry I was confused between the reputation system and marking answer as correct , because whenever I click the up arrow button for reputation it says that you need 15 points at least and I have 10 points

So sorry for that I have marked the answer as correct :)